# moment.js javascript dat object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Folks,
  I would like to have moment.js return a Javascript Date object in `UTC`.  Everything I've tried, it returns it back as a javascript object, but in `EST` (my local timezone).

The following does not seem to work:

```
var test1 = moment.utc(_.now()).format();
console.log('test1',test1); //2015-01-15T01:04:51+00:00
var test2 = moment.utc(_.now()).toDate();
console.log('test2',test2); //Wed Jan 14 2015 20:05:39 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Did I misread their docs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, moment.toDate() returns a new Date() object unless _offset is not False equivalent.

```
toDate : function () {
  return this._offset ? new Date(+this) : this._d;
}
```

is the the relevant code.  ECMAscript 5 says new Date() objects should be UTC format.  ECMAscript 6 says new Date() is local time format.  V8 seems to support ECMAscript 6.

Looks like you shouldn't use moment().utc().toDate() to get a UTC date object.

some references

- [moment.js toDate function](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.js#L2212)
- [V8 Date constructor bug](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2837)

Comment: Same output, `test1 2015-01-15T01:21:20+00:00` `test2 Wed Jan 14 2015 20:21:20 GMT-0500 (EST)`

Comment: Very strange.  What are you running this from?  I would guess node.js from the tags.

Comment: would you suggest a library that fully supports this transformation? Thanks!!